# Generate password hashes for user registration on Kohana

Tags: php, passwords, kohana, salt

I can't register new users, or modify user passwords, on our Kohana built website app. I do have access to our database and can change passwords there but I need a way to generate password hashes from strings which will be accepted by the system.

How can I use `hash_password(passwordstring, FALSE)` to display the hash I should insert into the DB?

Is there anything in the **modules/auth/classes/kohana/auth.php** file that I should be looking at?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `echo Auth::instance()->hash_password('new password')`. You dont need pass `$salt` value because it will be generated automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Kohana is just a framework, its not a user system. You will need to provide the code for the hash_password function as this looks like a library of some sort.

Comment: Its a default Kohana's Auth module.